# Flutter: how to include 'Instance of Model' from json_serializable to http post body?

Tags: flutter

```
  var user = userModel(userName) as Map;
  print(user);
  // var _response =
  await http.post(
      Uri.parse('urllll'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: user);
```

I am trying to include `user` to the `http-post-body` using `json_serializable`. However, I am getting `Invalid argument(s): Invalid request body "Instance of 'userModel'".` error.

Is it possible to include like that or do I have to decode to `Map` to send it over? If this is the case then what is the point of including  `Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$userModelToJson(this);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a model in a class and in the model set the functions of converting the class instance to `Json` and vice versa.

```
class MyModel {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  MyModel(this.id, this.name);

  factory MyModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MyModel(json['ID'], json['Name']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'ID': id,
        'Name': name,
      };
}
```

then Then convert the instance to the Json string using the `toJson()` defined function

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<bool> postMethod(MyModel myModel) async {
    var jsonBody = jsonEncode(myModel.toJson());

    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse("your-url"),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: jsonBody,
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: But, what is the point of using `jsonEncode` if `toJson()` is about converting `Map` to `Json`?

Comment: I have not tested this yet but I think you can use either